# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper

Tags: android, spring

I have a project for Spring android basic auth.

The Project for auth is:- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android-samples/tree/master/spring-android-basic-auth

This in file Go-to :- `.....\Downloads\spring-android-samples-master\spring-android-basic-auth\client`

The Jar File i added is:

```
spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.1.jar
```

The error occurs in :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
```

But steel i get error of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.

Please help me to solve this issue.

I am new to android please help to solve this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `org.spring-framwork.web.jar` to your classpath.

Comment: I add this jar file but steel error occurs, please help me.

Comment: Looks like you need also `spring-android-rest-template.jar`

Comment: After adding this jar file  error occurs for : ResponseEntity<Message> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders), Message.class);                       And Error is :- The type org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: please help for this issue

Comment: MultiValueMap is a class containt in spring-core.jar. Add these jar also to your classpath.

Comment: I have added jar file "  spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar " Now error comes for Async Task , Error is for  @Override
  protected Message doInBackground(Void... params) { }  And Error shows :-- "  Multiple markers at this line
 - This method must return a result of type String
 - This method must return a result of type Message
 - implements 
  android.os.AsyncTask<java.lang.Void,java.lang.Void,org.springframework.android.basicauth.Message>.doInBackground"

Comment: Please add a new question in SO because that is a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have spring tools installed for your IDE ( assume you are using eclipse).

if you have not installed check below links.

http://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/install-spring-tool-suite-for-existing-eclipse-ide

If you already installed , refresh eclipse .

Comment: I am using eclipse for android project and error comes for android project also.