# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when already imported jar files to android studio

Tags: json, jar, android-studio, jackson, noclassdeffounderror

I receive the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` even after adding the Jackson `jar` files. In Android Studio?

Also tried a few links. Namely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211955/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-codehaus-jackson-map-objectmapper), which did not help.

Edit:

After some research I discovered the root of the error. The `dynamo-geo.jar` library that is provided by Amazon is inherently flawed in that it refers to some sort of outdated `Jackson` version. Upon looking in I can see that the class that is called `geoJsonMapper` refers to a deprecated version of `ObjectMapper` from the old `1.x.x` versions of `Jackson`. I opened source code from `dynamo-geo.jar` [here](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-geo) and I edited the `ObjectMapper` import from the outdated version to `import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;`.

Now the issue I have is I am not sure if there is a way to compile a `JAR` file in Android Studio? In order to get the newly updated library into my other Android Studio project?

EDIT:

Solution - [read this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/214).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jackson 2 then you will want to import `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` instead of `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper`. You may also have a mix of Jackson 1 and Jackson 2 JAR files in your classpath.

You should be able to fork [dynamodb-geo](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-geo), make your changes, and use Maven to package the new JAR file (run the command `mvn clean package`). The new JAR file would be located in `/dynamodb-geo/target/`.

Comment: I am indeed using Jackson 1. I checked the AmazonDB API's for java and they are using Jackson 1 as well.

Comment: I discovered the issue and am updating my problem further. I am still not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I already attempted using the older versions of Jackson. I am saying that the Dynamodb-geo.jar library that Amazon provides is inherently broken for the old versions of Jackson that I have tried. I already reimplemented a  new version of Jackson and it appears to work with that. It's just a matter of getting my newly edited library into my other project? Does this make sense?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I was wrong in my assumptions. Sorry to have wasted your time. Your solution is adequate for my other issue however I have edited in a solution to my problem. It appears it is merely the nature of Android Studio that caused the underlying issues.